# Heaviside function in NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, special-functions

I have:

```
so = NDSolve[{ss'[t] + 0.71/(1 + bb[t]) ss[t] - 0.31 ss[t] (1 - ss[t]/6.19) == 0, 
bb'[t] - 0.24 (1 - bb[t]) HeavisideTheta[18 - t] + 0.43 bb[t] ss[t] + 0.72 (1 - bb[t - 18]) == 0, 
ss[t /; t < 0] == 0.98, bb[t /; t < 0] == 1.11}, {ss, bb}, {t, 0, 30}];

Plot[Evaluate[bb[t] /. so], {t, 0, 30}, PlotRange -> All, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotLabel -> "B(t)"]
Plot[Evaluate[ss[t] /. so], {t, 0, 30}, PlotRange -> All, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotLabel -> "S(t)"]
```

It returns two warnings related to HeavisideTheta:

```
NDSolve::nlnum: The function value {0.0140543 +0.00193314 HeavisideTheta[0.],-0.00826042} is not a list of numbers with dimensions {2} at {t,bb[t],ss[t]} = {18.,0.991945,0.152732,1.11,0.98,0.991945,0.152732}.

NDSolve::nlnum: The function value <<1>>[18.,{0.991945,0.152732}] is not a list of numbers with dimensions {2} at {t,bb[t],ss[t]} = {18.,{0.991945,0.152732}}.
```

What are the meanings behind these warning and how they can be fixed? Thanks for your help!

Comment: It seems to be an internal  `NDSolve` message indicating `HeavisideTheat[0]`is undefined.

Comment: Please, note that the Heaviside theta function $\theta(x)$, equal to 0 for x<0 and 1 for x>0. Therefore, function `HeavisideTheta[0]` is not defined. Usually in numerical calculations we use the following definition  `HeavisideTheta[0.]->0.5`

Comment: @Tim Add before code `Unprotect[HeavisideTheta]; HeavisideTheta[0.] = 0.5; Protect[HeavisideTheta];`

Comment: Alternatively you can utilize `UnitStep` which is 0 for 0 < x and 1 for x>= 0. Doesn't suffer from being undefined at x = 0.

Comment: @AlexTrounev: Your advice produces "NDSolve::ndsz: At t == 29.51554154615575, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected" and the numbers of the order `10^53` which are not from the real world in the empty plot. `HeavisideTheta` is a distribution, not a usual function. In view of it `HeavisideTheta[0.] = 0.5;` does not make sense (see [that Wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=Distribution+%28mathematics%29&title=Special:Search&ns0=1) for info).

Comment: @Tim: Indeed, ` UnitStep` instead of `HeavisideTheta` works, but we see `10^53` in the second plot. Comparison with  [Plank constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=Planck+constant&title=Special:Search&ns0=1) says that `10^53` is not from the real world.

Comment: Change input to exact numbers and experiment with WorkingPrecision, and that 10^53 goes away.  UnitStep works better than 1/2 for HeavisideTheta[0].